# error on setOnclickListener in my activity

Tags: android

```
((Button)findViewById(2131230768)).setOnClickListener(new MainMenuActivity(this));
```

View.OnClickListener runGameListener = new MainMenuActivity(this);

I have implemented onclicklistener even though it gives error on mainmenuactivity

my class is

```
public class MainMenuActivity
  extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

please help me..

Comment: what is the meaning of this code

Comment: new MainMenuActivity(this)).create();
    }

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What errors are you getting? @RaviKumar

Comment: View cannot be resolved to a type
 - The constructor ProfilingActivity(ProfilingActivity) is 
  undefined

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have layout `sample_activity`.

Here's the code for `sample_activity.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO!!"
        android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And `MainActivity.class` :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button goButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);

        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //....Do all the stuffs here

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: i am having R.id,R.drawable,R.layout,R.string ,R.attr classes , my question is how to add these class values to corresponding xml files..  ex.. R.drawable code is     
public final class R$drawable
{
  public static final int ball_b = 2130837504;
  public static final int ball_g = 2130837505;
  public static final int ball_r = 2130837506;
  public static final int bar_test = 2130837507;
  public static final int drop = 2130837508;
  public static final int drop_title_b = 2130837509;
  public static final int drop_title_g = 2130837510;
}

Comment: What do you mean and what you want to achieve? Can you post the code in Original post? Couldn't read well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your id of button from xml is write or not? I think your id is wrong its giving error..

Answer (score 0):

First, never search for views by their generated id value. Use the identifier name instead, e.g.

```
findViewById(R.id.your_button)
```

Second, `new` with an `Activity` is not correct. Don't instantiate activities yourself.

Since your activity implements `View.OnClickListener` and assuming the code is in the same activity, just use

```
setOnClickListener(this)
```

That is,

```
findViewById(R.id.your_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

(`setOnClickListener()` is a `View` method so casting to `Button` is not needed here.)